# OneHotEncoder with Streaming Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming, one-hot-encoding

I would like to apply OneHotEncoder to multiple Columns in my Streaming Dataframe, but I've got the following error. 
Any suggestions?

Many thanks!

```
 Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Queries with streaming sources 
 must be executed with writeStream.start();;
```

CODE:
// Read csv

```
  val Stream = spark.read
  .format("csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("delimiter", ";")
  .option("header", "true")
  .schema(DFschema)
  .load("C:/[...]"/
```

// Kafka

```
   val properties = new Properties()
   //val topic = "mongotest"
   properties.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
   properties.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
   properties.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")

   Stream.selectExpr("CAST(Col AS STRING) AS KEY", 
   "to_json(struct(*)) AS value")
   .writeStream
   .format("kafka")
   .option("topic", "predict")
   .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
   .option("checkpointLocation", "C:[...]")
   .start()
```

Subscribe to topic

```
  val lines = spark.readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
  .option("subscribe", "predict")
  .load()

  val df = Stream
  .selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
  val jsons = df.select(from_json($"value", DFschema) as "data").select("data.*")
```

ETL[...]

Apply funcion Bucketizer() to field

```
 val Msplits = Array(Double.NegativeInfinity,7, 14, 21, Double.PositiveInfinity)
  val bucketizerM = new Bucketizer()
  .setInputCol("MEASURE")
  .setOutputCol("MEASURE_c")
  .setSplits(Msplits)

  val bucketedData1 = bucketizerD.transform(out)
  val bucketedData2 = bucketizerM.transform(bucketedData1) # Works
```

Error using OneHotEncoder()

```
  val indexer = new StringIndexer()
  .setInputCol("CODE")
  .setOutputCol("CODE_index")

  val encoder = new OneHotEncoder()
  .setInputCol("CODE")
  .setOutputCol("CODE_encoded")

  val vectorAssembler = new VectorAssembler()
 .setInputCols(Array("A","B", "CODE_encoded"))
 .setOutputCol("features")

  val transformationPipeline = new Pipeline()
 .setStages(Array(indexer, encoder, vectorAssembler))

  val fittedPipeline = transformationPipeline.fit(bucketedData2) # Does't work
```

Comment: Seems problem is with how you iterate records

Comment: How does `lines` become `out`? I don't see it in the code above.

Comment: I added the code you ask for. Many thanks! @JacekLaskowski